# Get python script to run on boot up in mac

Tags: python, macos, boot

How would I get a python script to run everytime the computer boots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to run a shell script on startup (OSX)](http://www.osxfaq.com/Tutorials/LearningCenter/HowTo/Startup/index.ws)

And in that script just call your program

```
python path/to/yourScript.py
```

EDIT: Since 2010 the above link has gone sour. But also since 2010 have some answers popped up the describe similar methods, eg.

[Running script upon login mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac)

[How to get shell scripts to run on startup - Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156288/how-to-get-shell-scripts-to-run-at-startup-on-yosemite)

Comment: fyi, the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [login hook](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420?viewlocale=en_US) (be careful, it runs as root)