# Running script upon login in mac OS X

Tags: bash, shell, automation, osx-snow-leopard

I am wondering if anyone is able to help me out with getting a shell (.sh) program to automatically run whenever I log in to my account on my computer. I am running Mac OS X 10.6.7.

I have a file "Example.sh" that I want to run when I log onto my computer. I do not have a problem running it when I am already logged in, but I want this to run automatically.

Answer (score 521, accepted):

Follow this:

- start `Automator.app`
- select `Application`
- click `Show library` in the toolbar (if hidden)
- add `Run shell script` (from the `Actions/Utilities`)
- copy & paste your script into the window
- test it
- save somewhere (for example you can make an `Applications` folder in your HOME, you will get an `your_name.app`)
- go to `System Preferences` -> `Users & Groups` -> `Login items` (or `System Preferences` -> `Accounts` -> `Login items` / depending of your MacOS version)
- add this app
- test & done ;)

**EDIT:**

*I've recently earned a "Good answer" badge for this answer. While my solution is simple and working, the cleanest way to run any program or shell script at login time is described in [@trisweb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372744/805031)*, **unless, you want interactivity**.

With automator solution you can do things like next:
[image: automator screenshot login application]

so, asking to run a script or quit the app, asking passwords, running other automator workflows at login time, conditionally run applications at login time and so on...

Comment: @GregMiernicki LOL, good morning... ;) Nearly a year ago added an EDIT to my answer, where telling this too. But, this is a bit simpler for average users, because creating XML (plist) files, is not very user friendly for many users. Anyway - thanx for a comment. ;)

Comment: @GregMiernicki and don't forget, with the Automator solution you can make INTERACTIVE login-scripts - e.g. a script what will ask you for some entry (e.g. additional password or anything like). The world isn't only _black or white_ - at least, it is like a zebra... :) :)

Comment: Say, I want to auto run a Python script (basically it will act as a daemon) automatically on start up. Is it possible to run the shell script like you said and invoke the Python script from within?

Comment: @Cupidvogel  Running an daemon at the login time is exactly the job for the launchd solution - see trisweb's answer. If you can manage a python daemon, youre sure can manage an plist config file where you can manage all aspects of restarts and so on...

Comment: Any idea on how to execute the script as root?

Comment: To run a script as root: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2571517?tstart=0 Example `do shell script "sudo ~/login.sh" with administrator privileges`

Comment: Kudos for pointing out the other answer as being the cleanest. That should get a good citizenship badge :).

Comment: Amazing answer. Do export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH, at the beginning of the script, if you want to run commands like "composer global update" on system startup.

Comment: @Leonardo In my case I made a script that updates Python packages and I needed `PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` to make it work. So it might vary depending on the needs. Thanks for the tip, btw!

Comment: Great and concise answer! One request for change - System Preferences now contains `Users & Groups` instead of `Accounts`

Comment: Now `Users & Groups > Login Items` supports `SH` scripts directly. No need to create this `.app` wrapper.

Comment: Simple, details, easy to follow.

Answer (score 460):

tl;dr: use OSX's native process launcher and manager, `launchd`.

To do so, make a `launchctl` daemon. You'll have full control over all aspects of the script. You can run once or keep alive as a daemon. In most cases, this is the way to go.

1. Create a `.plist` file according to the [instructions in the Apple Dev docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ) or more detail below.
2. Place in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`
3. Log in (or run manually via `launchctl load [filename.plist]`)

For more on `launchd`, [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) is quite good and describes the system and its advantages over other older systems.

---

Here's the specific plist file to run a script *at login*.

> Updated 2017/09/25 for OSX El Capitan and newer (credit to [José Messias Jr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520926/jos%C3%A9-messias-jr)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.user.loginscript</string>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array><string>/path/to/executable/script.sh</string></array>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Replace the `<string>` after the Program key with your desired command (note that any script referenced by that command must be executable: `chmod a+x /path/to/executable/script.sh` to ensure it is for all users).

Save as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.loginscript.plist`

Run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.loginscript.plist` and log out/in to test (or to test directly, run `launchctl start com.user.loginscript`)

Tail `/var/log/system.log` for error messages.

The key is that this is a User-specific launchd entry, so it will be run on login for the given user. System-specific launch daemons (placed in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`) are run on boot.

If you want a script to run on login for all users, I believe LoginHook is your only option, and that's probably the reason it exists.

Comment: Yes. FWIW I found this blog on the same technique helpful: http://developernotes.com/archive/2011/04/06/169.aspx

Comment: You neglect to mention what is dubious about Automator actions, and why they're 'not recommended'.

Comment: Here's a good overview about folder actions vs launchctl: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63731/38290 - And another about one of LoginHook's limitations (only one script allowed) - http://superuser.com/a/377401. It's not really that either is a dubious or poor method, but `launchctl` is simply far better in most cases, and gives you more control over all possible aspects of running your script. It's more in the sense of "why use a less capable method when launchd exists?" (Note I've changed the first sentence to indicate that I *personally* do not recommend these for this situation).

Comment: Wondering how you will create LaunchDaemon plist what will run everytime **when the user logging in?**. So, not when the system boots, but **everytime** when the user logging in (try with logout-login cycle). Can you please show **exactly** (not only bla-bla) how to implement the above (by you wrong) automator solution with launchctl?

Comment: @cajwine: edited with example as requested. Apologies for the 'bla bla'.

Comment: Please, take my excuses. ;) Now, YES - this is the cleanest solution and the most important part of your answer is: **The key is that this is a User-specific launchd entry, so it will be run on login for the given user.**

Comment: Plist files in _/Library/LaunchAgents/_ are run at login with the id of the logged in user. Plist files in _/Library/LaunchDaemons/_ are run at boot time as root (id can be changed with _User_ key).

Comment: In my case, in MacOS X El Capitan this example loaded, but it did not started the script. I had to change the .plist file in the Program Key like that:
`<key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
 <string>/path/to/myscript.sh</string>
 </array>`

Comment: I made a script that automatically executes instructions described by @trisweb (you only need to pass bash script path) link: https://github.com/myhau/add-startup-script-macos

Comment: That just doesn't work… It’s not executing the script.

Comment: Hi @chitzui - did you see the updates for the newer OSX versions? I've updated the instructions so all the code is up to date, so please try again and see if it works with the present example.

Comment: Since macOS distinguishes between 'login' and 'login after locking the screen', it's virtually useless for people who lock their screens and want something to run when they login afterwards.

Comment: It worked for me.  However, I had to chmod +x the script .

Comment: if you get "Service exited with abnormal code: 127" with  launchctl  but your scripts works correctly when run directly try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604119/osx-launchd-plist-for-node-forever-process/26389976#26389976

Comment: is this confirmed to work on Mojave? I have created my plist and load it as directed, but no error is returned and it does not show up in "launchctl list", nor does anything when started (no error or message in syslog either)

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that the shell script must be executable for this to work. (i.e. `chmod a+x /script/location.sh`)

Comment: To run a script as root when you log in to your Mac, [create a login hook](https://support.apple.com/zh-cn/HT2420).

Comment: To add to @JanKyuPeblik comment, on Catalina it works while logging out then back in, but it does not work when logging in after a reboot.  This answer appears to be simply outdated.  What probably will work is to disable SIP and re-mount OS (see https://www.launchd.info/ -> Troubleshooting -> bottom of page)

Comment: Will this work with a single-line command instead of a script? (Say, `echo "hello"` as opposed to `/path/to/script.sh`)

Comment: Let me add that in order to run the login service you first have to load it, then run (or log out and in) and if you make changes you must first unload it before doing step 1 & 2 again.   
`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.loginscript.plist` ,  
`launchctl start com.user.loginscript`,  
`launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.loginscript.plist`

Comment: I recently created my own startup plist using `launchctl`/`launchd` and it didn't work for me right away. I eventually got it working, wanted to share some tips, there were quite a few issues in my case:

* `chmod +x /Users/myusername/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.mystartupscript.plist` - to make sure the `LaunchAgents` `plist` is executable

* `chmod +x /Users/myusername/mystartupscript.sh` - to make sure your script is executable

Comment: * **This was the root cause in my case**:

  When `launchd` executes the `Program` command from your `plist` - the `PATH` environment variable is **empty** (crazy, right?). So you have to explicitly set the `PATH` environment variable in the `plist`:
  ```
   <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
   <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/usr/bin:/bin/:$PATH</string>
   </dict>
     ```

Comment: * It's extremely hard to play the "guessing game" when debugging why `launchd` doesn't execute something. By default `launchd` redirects the StdOut/StdErr to `/dev/null`. I suggest you redirect it to a file in `/tmp`. That helped me to debug and fix my startup script:
   ```
   <key>StandardOutPath</key>
   <string>/tmp/mystartupscript.log</string>
   <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
   <string>/tmp/mystartupscript.log</string>
   ```

Comment: * it's also a good idea to set a working directory explicitly for your startup scrip:
   ```
   <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
   <string>/Users/myusername/</string>   
   ```
 * whenever you make changes to the `launchd` `plist`, you need to force reload it:
   ```
   launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.mystartupscript.plist
   launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.mystartupscript.plist
   ```

Comment: * `plist` itself is a text XML, with additional rules. Easy to mess up. Always check that it's correct, like this:
   ```
   % plutil ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.mystartupscript.plist
   /Users/myusername/Library/LaunchAgents/com.user.mystartupscript.plist: OK
   ```

Answer (score 61):

1. Create a shell script named as `login.sh` in your $HOME folder.
2. Paste the following one-line script into Script Editor: `do shell script "$HOME/login.sh"`
3. Then save it as an application.
4. Finally add the application to your login items.

If you want to make the script output visual, you can swap step 2 for this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  do script "$HOME/login.sh"
end tell
```

If multiple commands are needed something like this can be used:

```
tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  do script "cd $HOME"
  do script "./login.sh" in window 1
end tell
```

Comment: I linked this one, the only thing missing a command line installer ;)

Comment: Nice solution. How can I hide the "login" window? I tried ticking in login items.

Comment: @xgdgsc: Goto `Go to System Preferences -> Accounts -> Login items` and check hide box for this application.

Comment: @anubhava As I said, I already checked the hide box for this login application. But it still appear and need to be forced to quit when shutting down the computer.

Comment: @xgdgsc: Oh ok, did you check `~/Library/LaunchAgents` folder?

Comment: @anubhava: I checked and there seems nothing relevant to this login application. I don' t know what it should be like.

Comment: @xgdgsc: Try searching some keyword in `.plist` files in 3 locations: `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`, `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Comment: If you got Permission denied  just execute command "chmod u+x login.sh"

Comment: If you want to minimize terminal window automatically then you can add following step after `do script` step: `set miniaturized of window 1 to true`