# Git keeps asking me for my ssh key passphrase

Tags: git, ssh-agent

I created keys as instructed in the github tutorial, registered them with github, and tried using ssh-agent explicitly — yet git continues to ask me for my passphrase every time I try to do a pull or a push.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762034/push-to-github-without-password-using-ssh-key

Answer (score 1599, accepted):

Once you have started the SSH agent with:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Do either:

1. To add your private key to it:

   ```
    ssh-add
   ```

   This will ask you your passphrase just once, and then you should be allowed to push, provided that you uploaded the public key to Github.
2. To add and save your key permanently on **macOS**:

   ```
    ssh-add -K
   ```

   This will persist it after you close and re-open it by storing it in user's keychain.

   If you see a warning about `deprecated` flags, try the new variant:

   ```
    ssh-add --apple-use-keychain
   ```
3. To add and save your key permanently on **Ubuntu** (or equivalent):

   ```
     ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```

Comment: log-out of the server, ssh back in, run `git pull`, prompt me for password again.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It is still asking for passphrase when I close Gitbash and open it again.

Comment: @OmarTariq If you close your git-bash session, you lose the ssh-agent instance. Some desktop environments launch a global agent so added keys are shared across terminal sessions, but that's specific to the OS you are using.

Comment: I'd just like to add another bit of info: If you have multiple ssh keys, you may want to specify the path to a particular id_rsa in your `ssh-add` command, e.g. `ssh-add /Users/rubyx/.ssh/git/id_rsa`

Comment: `ssh-add -K` will persist it after you close and re-open it by storing it in user's keychain.

Comment: @Kirk `ssh-add -K` gives the following:
`unknown option -- K
usage: ssh-add [options] [file ...]
Options:
  -l          List fingerprints of all identities.
  -L          List public key parameters of all identities.
  -k          Load only keys and not certificates.
  -c          Require confirmation to sign using identities
  -t life     Set lifetime (in seconds) when adding identities.
  -d          Delete identity.
  -D          Delete all identities.
  -x          Lock agent.
  -X          Unlock agent.
  -s pkcs11   Add keys from PKCS#11 provider.`

Comment: This just prevents you having to retype it repeatedly. If you literally don't want any security, ever, then don't put a password on the key.

Comment: I still get prompted for a passphrase regardless.

Comment: I had to do this `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` for it to persist on Mac.

Comment: This was not working for me on Windows. But the following command solved my problem:
`git config credential.helper store`
After that I was asked one more time for my credentials, but after that no more.

Comment: `-K` is apple specific. See https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: The option in linux is -k in lower case.

Comment: @PaulozOiOzuLLuFabrício I don't think that is correct, it lists -k as being the following on my Debian machine: `-k Load only keys and not certificates.`

Comment: @eztam "Using this helper will store your passwords unencrypted on disk, protected only by filesystem permissions. If this is not an acceptable security tradeoff, try git-credential-cache[1], or find a helper that integrates with secure storage provided by your operating system.
This command stores credentials indefinitely on disk for use by future git programs."

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Could you explain a little further how it works?

Comment: For Mac the k is in lower case not caps

Comment: That should be eval "${ssh-agent}" instead of eval ${ssh-agent}.

Comment: for mac OS you can use `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain`

Comment: `--apple-use-keychain` is new variant of `-K` see: ```WARNING: The -K and -A flags are deprecated and have been replaced
         by the --apple-use-keychain and --apple-load-keychain
         flags, respectively.  To suppress this warning, set the
         environment variable APPLE_SSH_ADD_BEHAVIOR as described in
         the ssh-add(1) manual page.```

Comment: I don't think this reply answers the question (and seems to be OS-specific, while the question is not)...

Comment: I tried everything else, but re-running `ssh-add -K` worked.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I'm still getting prompted for my passphrase.

Answer (score 356):

This has been happening to me after restarts since upgrading from OS X El Capitan (10.11) to macOS Sierra (10.12). The `ssh-add` solution worked temporarily but would not persist across another restart.

The permanent solution was to edit (or create) `~/.ssh/config` and enable the `UseKeychain` option.

```
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
```

Related: [macOS keeps asking my ssh passphrase since I updated to Sierra](https://superuser.com/questions/1127067/macos-keeps-asking-my-ssh-passphrase-since-i-updated-to-sierra)

Comment: worked for me thanks... 
I had done... `ssh-add -K /Users/***/.ssh/git/id_rsa` but it was still not working after terminal restart... thank you.

Comment: Want to why this happen? Read the technical note on OpenSSH changes https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html

Comment: Thanks, the accepted solution wasn't enough, but your solution did the trick ! (I'm on a mac M1).

Comment: Had the `~/.ssh/config` as per github tutorial and it didn't work. It worked only once added lines in this answer. Probably `Host *.github.com` wasn't working for `github.com`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I set min to `Host *github*`, which worked for me.

I didn't want to use `Host *`, as I also SSH into a RaspberryPi with a different setup

Answer (score 86):

If you've tried `ssh-add` and you're still prompted to enter your passphrase then try using `ssh-add -K`. This adds your passphrase to your keychain.

*Update: if you're using macOS Sierra then you likely need to do another step as the above might no longer work. Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`:*

```
Host *
  UseKeychain yes
```

Comment: Still prompts me for a passphrase.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Are you using macOS Sierra? If so, check out what I just added to the answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I am on Sierra.  However, here is the line that worked worked for me too: **AddKeysToAgent yes**

Comment: This also works with BitBucket Cloud.  I was having issues in GitKraken and this resolved my issues.

Answer (score 68):

I would try the following:

1. Start [GitBash](https://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/install-git-bash)
2. Edit your `~/.bashrc` file
3. Add the following lines to the file

```
SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment

# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > ${SSH_ENV}
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 ${SSH_ENV}
    . ${SSH_ENV} > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . ${SSH_ENV} > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

4. Save and close the file
5. Close GitBash
6. Reopen GitBash
7. Enter your passphrase

Comment: For future reference, this also works with `zsh`. Just add this to `.zshrc`

Comment: I believe this assumes your keyfile is called `id_rsa`. If you have a custom name, you should use eg. `/usr/bin/ssh-add ~/.ssh/custom_filename`

Comment: Can you explain what happen to this script?

Comment: @Lee it starts the ssh-agent if not already running, which is what makes sure not to ask you the ssh passphrase on every push (more or less).

Comment: This just runs ssh-agent and adds the key on every login. You still have to enter password each time you login. So for example if you have scripts ssh-ing and doing GIT commands, this is unfortunately not useful at all.

Comment: @trainoasis It is not true for me. I had to add a password only once.  I think the reason is that it creates .ssh/environment.

Comment: Where is .bashrc file located?

Comment: @nzim in your home directory (`~/` points to the home dir).

Comment: @Roland It doesn't work for me on windows if home dir is `C:\Users\%userprofile%\`, not for `~/.profile` not for `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 58):

What worked for me on Windows was (I had cloned code from a repo 1st):

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add 
git pull
```

at which time it asked me one last time for my passphrase

Credits: the solution was taken from
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/how-to-avoid-being-asked-passphrase-each-time-i-push-to-bitbucket

Comment: if you are using a non default rsa file name, then be sure to use it on the second command: `ssh-add /c/Users/you_user/.ssh/id_rsa_abcxyz`

Comment: this only works while the gitbash is active for me. Once I close it, again I need to provide credentials

Answer (score 48):

Try adding this to your **~/.ssh/config**:

```
Host *
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

... assuming your private key is named **id_rsa**

Comment: UseKeychain yes is only valid for mac

Comment: @Oz123 what's the equivalent for windows

Comment: @Oz123 I think the equivalent on Windows is AddKeysToAgent yes check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423626/remember-git-passphrase-in-wsl

Comment: This is a much more universal answer than the others (works on any OS, except for the UseKeyChain part). I should be the accepted answer IMHO.   Thanks @IgorGanapolsky

Comment: Excellent. How would you go about specifying several ssh keys if you have accounts in Gitlab, Github, etc. and you are managing projects locally to push to those?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein For your case, instead of `Host *`, you'd specify each **Host** name separately.

Answer (score 25):

previously -K flag is used to add key but now:

```
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain
```

The -K and -A flags are deprecated and have been replaced
by the --apple-use-keychain and --apple-load-keychain
flags, respectively.

---

LATER EDIT: you may need to add `ssh-add --apple-load-keychain -q` to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or equivalent.

Comment: For me this, worked. I was trying to import a private github repo via SSH

Comment: I had to to do that and also add `ssh-add --apple-load-keychain -q` to my `.bash_profile` (or `.zshrc` if you use zsh).

Comment: Same here, I had to add what @AndréWillikValenti said to my `.zshrc`

Comment: Thanks @alexventuraio, I added that step to the original answer.

Answer (score 19):

Run the following:

```
eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa &>/dev/null
```

Enter the passphrase, then check git. Git should not ask for passphrase after this command.

The original source: https://gist.github.com/egoens/c3aa494fc246bb4828e517407d56718d

Answer (score 15):

If you are not using GitBash and are on Windows - you need to start your ssh-agent using this command

```
start-ssh-agent.cmd
```

If your ssh agent is not set up, you can open PowerShell as admin and set it to manual mode

```
Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
```

Comment: I started the agent but it still asks me for my passphrase every time

Answer (score 12):

If the above solutions are not working for me, one thing to check is that you actually have the public key too (typically `id_rsa.pub`). It is unusual not to, but that was the cause for me.

To create your public key from your private key:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: This did it for me! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, but the other answers didn't fix my problem.  I thought I'd go ahead and post this just in case someone else has a screwy setup like me.

It turns out I had multiple keys and Git was using the wrong one first.  It would prompt me for my passphrase, and I would enter it, then Git would use a different key that would work (that I didn't need to enter the passphrase on).

I just deleted the key that it was using to prompt me for a passphrase and now it works!

Answer (score 8):

In case you are on Win10:

I had the same problem.
(previously had to update ssh-agent individually with a script from [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1263#issuecomment-499542944) because of a different problem)

Git did access my ssh config (git pull threw exceptions when I had nonsense-lines in ssh config), but never seemed to care about the private key I had added via ssh-agent and referenced in my config.

What fixed the problem was to execute the following command in PowerShell:

```
git config core.sshCommand (get-command ssh).Source.Replace('\','/')
```

(Details are in this [link](https://www.teapotcoder.com/post/how-to-fix-git-ssh-asking-for-password-on-windows-10/))

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you may be having trouble with SSH-Agent itself. I would try troubleshooting that.

1) Did you do ssh-add to add your key to SSH?

2) Are you closing the terminal window between uses, because if you close the window you will have to enter the password again when you reopen it.

Comment: Would be nice to add information on how to solve the first problem Jeff Welling.

Answer (score 7):

For **Windows** or **Linux** users, a possible solution is described on [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases), which I report below for your convenience.

You can run `ssh-agent` automatically when you open bash or Git shell. Copy the following lines and paste them into your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file:

```
env=~/.ssh/agent.env

agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_start () {
    (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
    . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }

agent_load_env

# agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)

if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add
elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
    ssh-add
fi

unset env
```

If your private key is not stored in one of the default locations (like `~/.ssh/id_rsa`), you'll need to tell your SSH authentication agent where to find it. To add your key to ssh-agent, type `ssh-add ~/path/to/my_key`.

Now, when you **first run** Git Bash, you are prompted for your passphrase. **The `ssh-agent` process will continue to run until you log out, shut down your computer, or kill the process.**

Comment: Here's the link to the *specific* section on the page [*Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows*](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows).  Note: You must select the "Windows" tab on the page to see this section... there is no Linux tab listed, so I find this confusing on GitHub's part.

Comment: Where is this ~/.profile file is located?

Comment: @nzim you have to create it (if it doesn't exist) in C:\Users\<your-user>\.profile
The "~" in a path, like "~/.profile", usually means your system user folder.

Answer (score 4):

I try different solutions but nothing help. But this steps ([My GitBash SSH environment always asks for my passphrase, what can I do?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/my-gitbash-ssh-environment-always-asks-for-my-passphrase-what-can-i-do-277252540.html)) from Bitbucket.com seams works well :

The idea is:

1. you create `~/.bashrc` file
2. add follow script:

   ```bash
    SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment

    # start the ssh-agent
    function start_agent {
        echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
        # spawn ssh-agent
        /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
        echo succeeded
        chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
        . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
        /usr/bin/ssh-add
    }

    if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
        . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
        ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
            start_agent;
        }
    else
        start_agent;
    fi
   ```
3. re-run Bash

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution that is not mentioned above is to check your remote with the following command:

```
git remote -v
```

If the remote does not start with git but starts with https you might want to change it to git by following the example below.

```
git remote -v // origin is https://github.com/user/myrepo.git
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/myrepo.git
git remote -v // check if remote is changed
```

Comment: This worked for me. in my case, I mistakenly set remote to git@github.com instead of  https://github.com.

Comment: worked for me as well, I didn't specify the user anymore, just this; `origin git@github.com/myrepo.git`

Answer (score 1):

on mac,
if your ssh key need passphrase everytime and you want to skip it, then you can try below, it works fine for me

1. eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
2. ssh-add -K .ssh/id_rsa
3. add this default ssh configuration works for me

Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 1):

Update the url of the origin remote using SSH instead of HTTPS;

```
git remote set-url origin "SSH URL COPIED FROM GIT REPO."
```

This what works with me.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using fish, there's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/josh-padnick/c90183be3d0e1feb89afd7573505cab3) for it:

```
# config.fish
if not pgrep -f ssh-agent > /dev/null
  eval (ssh-agent -c)
  set -Ux SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  set -Ux SSH_AGENT_PID $SSH_AGENT_PID
  set -Ux SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This command from [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#adding-or-changing-a-passphrase) did the trick for me:

```
> Enter old passphrase: [Type old passphrase]
> Key has comment 'your_email@example.com'
> Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type new passphrase]
> Enter same passphrase again: [Repeat the new passphrase]
> Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Just changing to a new password won't help much and an empty password is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your local repo hasnt updated with ssh keys...at least this is what happened to me when going from https to ssh.

Have you done a remote reset?

```
git remote set-url origin <ssh url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Idk if someone needs something different but this help me a lot
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445525/11891580

To me on every restart, I have to run `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain` to load credentials, so I add this command to the stack overflow answer and now its fixed

Answer (score 0):

For skipping the passphrase we can create key without passphrase )))
But if this isn't a way to go
For Windows I'm using the ssh-agent, you can add private key in it and remove from .ssh folder. How to setup ssh-agent:

```
# Check the current status of ssh-agent:
Get-Service | ?{$_.Name -like '*ssh-agent*'} | select -Property Name, StartType, Status

# Start the Service:
Start-Service ssh-agent

# Add your key as before:
ssh-add <path to the key>
```

ssh-agent works with `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`
So we can setup this ssh.exe for git by creating environment variable:

```
GIT_SSH: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

This will be working for Git and Bash.

Also we can setup this path for TortoiseGit: Settings>Network>SSH>SSH Client

Answer (score -1):

you should now use `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain`on zsh, MacOS Sonoma

Comment: Already suggested in an earlier answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72196089/4473699 by @thowfeeq

Answer (score -2):

Maybe not the most secure way to fix this, but simply do not set a passphrase, it is optional. If you don't set a passphrase, it will not ask for it. You can change the passphrase with

```
$ ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
> Enter old passphrase: [Type old passphrase]
> Key has comment 'your_email@example.com'
> Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type new passphrase]
> Enter same passphrase again: [Repeat the new passphrase]
> Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

Comment: don't do this folks, simply no.