# Push to GitHub without a password using ssh-key

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I generated an SSH key pair without a password and added the public key to GitHub.

Connection with

```
user@dev:/var/www/project# ssh -T git@github.com
Hi User! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

was successful and when I rename the key, it fails.

But when I want to push my changes, it stills ask me for my username and password combination.

Is there a way to push without a password?

Comment: Make sure you are not using `https://github...` in your remotes. They should also follow the `git@github...` format.

Comment: [about-remote-repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/about-remote-repositories#about-remote-repositories) two type: 1. HPPT like ``https://github.com/user/repo.git`` 2. SSH, like ``git@github.com:user/repo.git``

Answer (score 728, accepted):

If it is asking you for a **username** and password, your origin remote is pointing at the HTTPS URL rather than the SSH URL.

Change it to ssh.

For example, a GitHub project like Git will have an HTTPS URL:

```
https://github.com/<Username>/<Project>.git
```

And the SSH one:

```
git@github.com:<Username>/<Project>.git
```

You can do:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<Username>/<Project>.git
```

to change the URL.

Comment: This solved it, but I keep asking myself why would Github then advise you to point a new repository's remote end to an http URL by default. I just created a repository from scratch, and I was presented with an option for setting an https remote URL, not a git one.

Comment: Here's a quick one-liner shell command that will automatically change your https url to the appropriate git one (Only works for github urls!): `git remote set-url origin $(git remote show origin | grep "Fetch URL" | sed 's/ *Fetch URL: //' | sed 's/https:\/\/github.com\//git@github.com:/')`

Comment: will it work for multiple `github` or `bitbucket` repostories and multiple accounts, will they conflict with each other?

Answer (score 34):

In case you are indeed using the SSH URL, but still are asked for username and password when git pushing:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<Username>/<Project>.git
```

You should try troubleshooting with:

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

Below is a piece of sample output:

```
...
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Yuci/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Yuci/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Yuci/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Yuci/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I actually have already added the public key to GitHub before, and I also have the private key locally. However, my private key is of a different name called `/c/Users/Yuci/.ssh/github_rsa`.

According to the sample output, Git is trying `/c/Users/Yuci/.ssh/id_rsa`, which I don't have. Therefore, I could simply copy `github_rsa` to `id_rsa` in the same directory.

```
cp /c/Users/Yuci/.ssh/github_rsa /c/Users/Yuci/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now when I run `ssh -vT git@github.com` again, I have:

```
...
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Yuci/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
...
Hi <my username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
...
```

And now I can push to GitHub without being asked for username and password :-)

Comment: why would anyone want to authenticate in any other way, huh? love this, thanks!

Comment: You might not have to copy the key to the other name; you could use something like `ssh-add 'C:\Users\Yuci\.ssh\github_rsa'` instead.

Answer (score 19):

As usual, create an SSH key and paste the public key to GitHub. Add the private key to ssh-agent. (I assume this is what you have done.)

To check everything is correct, use `ssh -T git@github.com`

Next, don't forget to modify the remote point as follows:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/your-repository.git
```

Answer (score 16):

Additionally for gists, it seems you must leave out the username

```
git remote set-url origin git@gist.github.com:<Project code>
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to use the **SSH** version, not **HTTPS**. When you clone from a repository, copy the link with the **SSH** version, because SSH is easy to use and solves all problems with access. You can set the access for every SSH you input into your account (like push, pull, clone, etc...)

Here is a link, which says why we need SSH and how to use it: step by step

[Git Generate SSH Keys](http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-generate-ssh-key-for-git.html)

Answer (score 5):

Like the other users mentioned, you must convert it from using HTTPS to SSH.  I don't see an answer with an end-to-end solution.  After [setting up the ssh keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), do (on your local machine) :

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/your_repo.git  # Convert HTTPS -> SSH
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github    # add private github ssh key ssh-agent (assuming you have it already running)
$ git push
```

Answer (score 5):

for using SSH you must use `$ git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` instead of `git remote add origin remote_repository_URL`.
you can check it with `$ git remote -v`, if you see 2 lines in the below format, it will work correctly:

```
origin git@github.com:username/repo-name.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:username/repo-name.git (push)
```

Answer (score 2):

You did everything ok but git still asking by password, this worked for me, execute the next commando in your current project's path:

```
~ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsaYourIdRsa
```

Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent and store your passphrase in the keychain. If you created your key with a different name, or if you are adding an existing key that has a different name, replace id_rsaYourIdRsa in the command with the name of your **private** key file.

Answer (score -5):

Using the command line:

Enter `ls -al ~/.ssh` to see if existing SSH keys are present.

In the terminal is shows: No directory exist

Then generate a new SSH key

Step 1.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

step 2.

```
Enter a file in which to save the key (/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa): <here is file name and enter the key>
```

step 3.

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a password]

Enter same passphrase again: [Type password again]
```

Comment: Sorry, this question is not about how to create the keys but to setup git to use the key instead of authentication