# Reassigning GitHub account on Mac through BASH terminal

Tags: git, github

I have a Mac with a bash terminal, Vagrant, and had it set up with a GitHub account that was associated with a programming company/class and now that I'm not longer a part of that, I need to switch my username and password to a new github account.  I don't need to reload the existing repository, and I already made a new one under a different account, but I can't push anything until I get my new password added.  I don't know the commands for putting in my password.  I followed this: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

But it doesn't tell me how to set up my password.  Also, the way it was set up before, I just had to do git add, git commit -m"", and git push origin master to push files into a repository.  I think I might have a password manager or something like that installed but I'm not sure how to go about changing that.  I can't add the new repository until I get the password set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is connect your Mac to a different github account.  If this is the case, you'd simply delete your SSH key from your old company/class from your "old" github account and upload your SSH key on your Mac to your other github account.

Once you do that, everything else should Just Work.™

You may also need to change some of the settings in your `~/.gitconfig` file, as that is where your username and email address is stored at a global level.

Comment: is that like doing this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762034/push-to-github-without-password-using-ssh-key
I'm not sure I know what the ssh key is (or does) so I'm not sure how to change it.  I haven't been typing in the github.com stuff like in the link above.  

Thanks for the response!

Comment: OK that link helped, thank you!  but when I try the clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub command it says " clip: command not found"
it produced the key fingerprint and the key's randomart image, but that command won't work.

Comment: Not sure what "clip" is - do you mean `pbcopy`?

Comment: that link says to:
Step 3: Add your SSH key to GitHub

Run the following code to copy the key to your clipboard.

clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
# Copies the contents of the id_rsa.pub file to your clipboard

and that's the part where it says the command is not found.  
Thank you again so much for still responding.  I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Interesting - what I see is this command:  `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: Ah, you somehow were looking at the Windows instructions...  Make sure you're looking at the Mac instructions. :)