# SSH without password between servers using public keys

Tags: unix, ssh, scp, public-key

I have generated a ssh-keygen from server1, transferred it to server2 (both Ubuntu servers) using scp, added it to the .ssh/authorized_keys and then changed the permissions to both directory and file. The problem is that when i try to ssh or scp from server1 to server2, it keeps asking me for the passphrase.

It worked perfectly from my mac to the server. I followed this [Git keeps asking me for my ssh key passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032461/git-keeps-to-ask-me-for-ssh-key-passphrase) which worked but after i logout from both servers, it keeps on asking me for the passphrase again. Can someone help me please?

Comment: have you tried to turn it off and on again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found that the solution was not to include a passphrase when you generate the ssh-keygen...