# Git SSH Key : Two different account for github and gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

Is there any way to operate **GitLab** and **GitHub** accounts through **SSH Key** by using two different email address?

I Have two mail id, `username@gmail.com` and `username@xyz.in` and I want to push some projects to gitlab as well as some other projects to github and also I want to avoid password entering prompt in every push command. Is it possible?

Comment: To avoid ssh asking for passphrase use [ssh-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10032655/7976758).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try working with ssh instead of https: upload your public ssh git to the server, and use an ssh url. For instance, for github you shouldn't have a url like

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
```

but you should have

```
git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git
```

--

Now, to use different ssh keys or username, you could try setting your `~/.ssh/config` file to something like

```
Host           gitlab.com
HostName       gitlab.com
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/gitlab
User           username@gmail.com

Host           github.com
HostName       github.com
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/github
User           username@xyz.in
```

Where`IdentityFile` are the path to your private ssh keys

Comment: But it's keep asking me `username` and `password` while pushing to the repository

Comment: It's perhaps because you're using an https url. I just updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I've looked enough in the web and this was the only really correct and true answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

One option for github is to use [personal access tokens](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens). Just log in to your account and go to your settings (click the dropdown beside your profile picture) then scroll to the bottom of the settings page and you will see a link to "Personal Access Tokens".

Then create a token with full access to repo (the other API access is not important if all you want to do is pull and push).

The token system was created to allow API access to github but it also work with HTTPS links.

Clone your repo using HTTPS instead of SSH (or if it's already SSH then just copy the HTTPS url and replace the SSH url in your `.git/config` file). Then edit your `.git/config` file and add the access token to the HTTPS url.

The syntax is standard Basic Auth syntax used by web browsers:

```
https://<YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME>:<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com
```

I use this to allow me to use github with multiple user accounts (for work, for my personal projects, for voluntary work etc.).