# Git keeps asking for my passphrase even though I have followed instructions

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh

I have followed the instructions over here (https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) but Git still keeps asking for my passphrase. I'm on windows and have already set up ssh and generated the key. I even used the -K argument on the command ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa but it doesn't seem to work. How should I correct this?

Comment: Did you check the key pair you use is correct (private and public key) on you git repo manager ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git keeps asking me for my ssh key passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032461/git-keeps-asking-me-for-my-ssh-key-passphrase)