# How to avoid add ssh key everytime when push or pull the code

Tags: windows, git, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I generated the ssh pub key and private key and register pub key to my github.
And add the private key by using this

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But I have to put this command everytime when I push or pull the code.
I hope to avoid this.

Comment: Try referring to answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032461/git-keeps-asking-me-for-my-ssh-key-passphrase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have to write those commands everytime.

First, the agent is only needed if your private key is passphrase protected.

Second, as explained in "[Working with SSH key passphrases](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases)", you should be able to automatically launch said agent through a `~/.bashrc` resource file, or (for Mac) caching the passphrase in the keychain.

Comment: I add the .bashrc file and my private key is not default id_rsa so I put the command ```ssh-add ~/path/to/mykey ``` . Now I don't need to add ssh key everytime. Thank you!