# GitHub ssh credentials

Tags: git, ssh

I created a new project and initiated a git project.
However After adding and commiting, when I try to push, they ask me passphrase which I'm 100% sure it's correct because if I fail in the command line, it asks again until achieves 3 tries.
The issue is when I write the correct pass, it asks again in a popup
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OstRE.png)
I enter again the pass and it continues asking again and again in loop. It's so annoying and I cann't find any help in the internet related with this.

Can someone please give me some help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git keeps asking me for my ssh key passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032461/git-keeps-asking-me-for-my-ssh-key-passphrase)

Comment: Are you using the wrong password? (is `~/.ssh/id_rsa` your proper SSH key?)

Comment: @StephenNewell Sorry, but this article "Git keeps asking me for my ssh key passphrase" talks about the need of authentication each time we want to push. My problem is worst: it asks repetitively for the password in a pop-up and never let me authenticate.

Comment: And did you run `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` like the answer suggested?