# How to run derby process "startNetworkServer" in background on mac

Tags: java, macos, unix, derby

I just migrated from Windows OS to MAC OSX El Capitan. 
In Windows I had idea how to run any .bat file as windows service on startup of system.
Please help me how to achieve the same in the mac so that on startup of mac system "startNetworkServer" derby unix executable should be started automatically in background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534379/how-do-i-set-terminal-scripts-to-run-at-start-up-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `nohup` unix command in conjunction with the `&` to run processes in background.

Type this in your macOS Terminal:

```
nohup startNetworkServer &
```

This should start your network server in the background and you should be able to exit the terminal also.

> **Update**

Wrap the above command in a shell script.

You can then use the built in utility [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) to configure the script to run at startup.

---

An alternate option would be to add the script to the user's Login Items under **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > *Select the User* > **Login Items**

Hope this helps!

Comment: would it run the process startup of my system everytime.

Comment: @SatishPahuja See my updated answer