# how to make nvm automatically sourced upon login

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am using nvm to manage the node version.

I like to make nvm sourced upon login,  so I dont have to do it manually everytime I login.

in my user home directory, there's a .bashrc file.   I appended following two lines to the end of the file. then restart my mac os.  after I login, nvm is not sourced.  I have to manually run them again.  coudln't figure out whats wrong. please help.

```
. ~/nvm/nvm.sh

nvm use 0.8.20
```

Comment: have you looked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac

Answer (score 7):

You need to put into your `.bash_profile` this line

```
[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Source the file (`source ~/.bash_profile`) or reopen the shell and then in the shell execute:

```
$ nvm alias default <version>
```

That would load node in any new shell you open.

Answer (score 4):

### Using `.nvmrc` file

It turns out that creating a `.nvmrc` file in your home directory is enough. It is loaded automatically when you open the terminal.

To create the `.nvmrc` file with the version we want to run *(0.12.2)*  do this:

```
echo '0.12.2' > ~/.nvmrc
```

#### If that for some reason doesn't work, force load the `nvm` from your `.bashrc`

But only if you're running in interactive mode.

Add the command to run `nvm use 0.12.2` *(or any other version you'd like to run)* if the shell is launched in interactive mode to the end of `.bashrc`.

```
echo '[[ $- == *i* ]] && nvm use 0.12.2' >> ~/.bashrc
```

**Boom, done! :)**

Comment: what does `"[[ $- == *i* ]]"` do? explainshell.com says it's a syntax error :-(

Answer (score 1):

For Mac at least, open your .profile file, and add this line in

```
[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && source "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" 
# Load NVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Done, bingo bango, GG.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the official website carefully as I used
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | zsh from https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm and it automatically does my work from installing to load automatically setup.