# IOS simulator slow with Mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, osx-mavericks

I'm the only one to have a slow simulator since the last OSX update (Mavericks)?

- I've tried to reset simulator
- I've tried to switch on/off animation speed in Debug main bar
- I've tried to draw my game with a simple moving quad
- I've tried to run my application on IOS7, IOS6 with Retina and without on the simulator
- My application isn't slow when I run it on an Android device

Simulator is always slow, on the previous OSX version I haven't got any problems :/
(My application is a game using OpenGL ES2)

Thanks!

Comment: "My application isn't slow when I run it on an Android device" huh?

Comment: I've got a personal Framework in C++ to make cross-platforms game, so I can run my game on Android, IOS, computer, ….

Comment: I've got the same problem, although it only seems to slow down when I'm using the iOS6.1 simulator, using the iOS7 simulator doesn't present the slow down issue. I've tried a number of combinations, but it doesn't matter if it's iPhone, iPad, iPhone Retina, iPhone 4"... the only common thing is using iOS6.1. Resetting the simulator, and even re-installing Xcode makes no difference. I am using Xcode 5, with the iOS6.1SDK installed along side iOS7SDK, but before updating to Mavericks, I never had this problem.

Comment: I've barely noticed this, as in my app it hardly matters. I've been wondering if turning off App Nap for the simulator might address this, but I might not even notice so I haven't bothered. If the impact is noticeable and repeatable to you, give that a try.

Comment: @StevenFisher I've tried to turn off App Nap (on the simulator application), that didn't change anything.

Comment: I haven't updated to Mavericks, but after the new XCode update, I'm getting the same issues with the simulator slowing down.

Comment: I think I read something in the Apple's release notes. Here's the link  : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241

Comment: I'm getting about 4 seconds to show a UIALertView (so you can see each individual animation frame). Slowdown is variable though, but stock UI transitions are all happening at least twice as slow as identical project yesterday pre-Mavericks. reallllly.....dogggggg....slooooowwwww

Comment: I am noticing this as well in the iOS 6 and 6.1 simulators. @SanjeetSuhag, I couldn't find any mention of this in the release notes. Are you sure you saw something there?

Comment: This is not Mavericks problem. Looks like that's problem with new SDK. There is only one solution I found, use iOS 7 simulator instead of older.

Comment: This is very noticeable for me. The simulator is terrible now. No change aside from updating to Mavericks. I'm using Xcode 4.6. Let's go Apple.

Comment: I filed a bug report on August 14th, 2013 with rdar://14734314 about this very same issue, but it is still open to this day. It only affects iOS 6 simulators on Mavericks, not 7.

Comment: Maverick is sluggish with 2GB of RAM using XCode 5 of retina simulators, should you upgrade with 4GB or 8GB

Answer (score 31):

I met the performance issue on simulator prior to iOS7.

Apple provides the solution in [Xcode 5.1 Release Note](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1_developer_preview_2_qizk9u/xcode_5.1_developer_preview_2__release_notes.pdf) (Page 4: iOS Simulator)

`sudo sysctl -w kern.timer.coalescing_enabled=0`

Now the simulator flies!

Comment: Just to note, this disables time coalescing in Mavericks, which may hurt battery life on laptops.

Comment: Yeah, we should enable it after using the simulator.Thanks.

Comment: @LeoNatan  `sudo sysctl -w kern.timer.coalescing_enabled=0` really does? I want to keep it disabled. What are the disadvantages to that beside battery life?

Comment: @Sha - it is an energy saving mechanism. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timer_coalescing

Comment: @LeoNatan Yea, just read all about it thanks. I think I'll leave it disabled for now. I don't want to reenable it after every time I'm using the simulator and my laptop is always connected to the power any way.

Comment: Also worth noting that the setting is switched back on again after you restart your computer. Is there a way of setting it permanently?

Comment: +1 Excellent answer!  Interestingly I had no slowdown with iOS 7 Simulator, just iOS 6.1.  Now I'm getting 60fps once again.  Many thanks.

Comment: @jowie follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac and copy paste the above terminal code as shell script

Answer (score 3):

Well, the iOS 6.1 simulator *seems slower* in Mavericks. I am still using XCode 4.6.3 and iOS 6.1, but on Mavericks now.

I'm not ready to upgrade my app to using iOS 7 (I'm holding off until I have enough time to handle any issues that may pop up in the upgrade).

A reasonable answer seems to the deleted one, he said that if you do use Mavericks, make sure to use the iOS 7 simulator, as it doesn't seem to have the slowdown issue.

[image]

#### Edit:

Having installed XCode 5, happily there were no problems in the upgrade with my project (I was afraid because of my experience with the Beta). The iOS 7 simulator on Mavericks runs at least as fast as the iOS 6.1 simulator on Lion.

When you're running in the simulator, **make sure not to select Retina**, because the retina emulator is many times slower than the non-retina emulator.  This is likely due to the fact that it has that many more pixels to fill, and the iOS simulators don't use hardware rendering.

Comment: Yeah, I just installed XCode 5, and happily there were no problems (I was afraid because of my experience with the Beta). So verified, the iOS 7 simulator on Mavericks runs at least as fast as the iOS 6.1 simulator on Lion.

Comment: How do you not select retina?  As far as I can tell, the only way you can do that is select "iPad".

Comment: Yes, "iPad" is the non-retina iPad.  You can tell because it will be 768x1024 pixels in its full size (CMD+1) mode.  "iPad Retina" will be 1536x2048px in full-size mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , iOS simulator is very slow on both ios6 and ios7 . there are issues in xcode5 . I just upgrade by xcode to 5.0.2.
It is little bit fast than xcode 5 on simulator but still not up to mark.