# How can I open application window on concrete desktop (bash, Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, bash

I would like to run bash script at every startup as explained here [Running script upon login mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac)

I have a few desktop screens

```
[1] - [2] - [3] - [4]
```

And I would like to create config file that describes which app should be run at which screen:

format:

```
#file #application #screen number
project xCode 1
project xCode 2
... terminal 3
```

I can run app from script with `open` command, but how can I specify at which screen?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you don't need any script involved to achieve your goal. Just open the application to be configured, move the application to the desired space, right click the icon in the dock and choose "current desktop" inside the options menu.

Comment: but I want to open different xcode projects in different desktops, if i select desktop for application all project will be opened in one desktop.

Comment: Ok, I see. I can't tell you how to do that. But wouldn't AppleScript be a better tool for your goal then?