# "Unable to run app in Simulator" from TeamCity build agent

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, teamcity

I'm seeing this error in my TeamCity build agent output:

```
...
[14:17:50][Step 2/2] Starting: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project Foobar/Foobar.xcodeproj -scheme foobarNightly SYMROOT=/Users/Me/buildAgent/work/e60c5dca158b2d23/Foobar/build OBJROOT=/Users/Me/buildAgent/work/e60c5dca158b2d23/Foobar/build test -sdk iphonesimulator8.1
[14:17:50][Step 2/2] in directory: /Users/Me/buildAgent/work/e60c5dca158b2d23
...
[14:17:53][Step 2/2] FoobarTests (BUILD)
[14:17:53]=== BUILD TARGET FoobarTests OF PROJECT Foobar WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
[14:17:53]Check dependencies
[14:17:53]Testing failed:
[14:17:53]  Test target FoobarTests encountered an error (Unable to run app in Simulator If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/yy/lc1xnprn1w3g98mcy5mprm5c0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2014-11-04_11:17:51-qkVM7k.log)
[14:17:53][Step 2/2] ** TEST FAILED **
[14:17:54][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 65
...
```

where the mentioned log contains:

```
...
2014-11-04 11:17:51.085 Beginning test session with Xcode 6A1052d
2014-11-04 11:17:51.085 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project Foobar/Foobar.xcodeproj -scheme foobarNightly SYMROOT=/Users/Me/buildAgent/work/e60c5dca158b2d23/Foobar/build OBJROOT=/Users/Me/buildAgent/work/e60c5dca158b2d23/Foobar/build test -sdk iphonesimulator8.1
2014-11-04 11:17:51.085 Testing on device: <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fcb257b2210> {
        SimDevice: SimDevice : iPad 2 (B694B12B-BAE3-48FD-A351-CFC5855B5D14) : state={ Booted } deviceType={ SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2 } runtime={ SimRuntime : 8.1 (12B411) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-1 }
}
2014-11-04 11:17:51.085 Initializing test infrastructure.
2014-11-04 11:17:51.085 Writing testing status log to /var/folders/yy/lc1xnprn1w3g98mcy5mprm5c0000gn/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2014-11-04_11:17:51-qkVM7k.log.
2014-11-04 11:17:51.107 Creating the connection.
2014-11-04 11:17:51.107 Listening for proxy connection request from the test bundle (all platforms)
2014-11-04 11:17:51.107 Resuming the connection.
2014-11-04 11:17:51.107 Test connection requires daemon assistance.
2014-11-04 11:17:51.469 Checking test manager availability..., will wait up to 120s
2014-11-04 11:17:52.148 testmanagerd handled session request.
2014-11-04 11:17:52.148 Waiting for test process to launch.
2014-11-04 11:17:53.323 Launch session started, setting a disallow-finish-token on the run operation.
2014-11-04 11:17:53.323 Waiting for test process to check in..., will wait up to 120s
2014-11-04 11:17:53.334 Adding console adaptor for test process.
2014-11-04 11:17:54.012 Test operation failure: Unable to run app in Simulator
2014-11-04 11:17:54.012 _finishWithError:Error Domain=IDEUnitTestsOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Unable to run app in Simulator" UserInfo=0x7fcb28ddd570 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to run app in Simulator} didCancel: 1
...
```

If I run the exact same command directly on the build agent machine:

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project Foobar/Foobar.xcodeproj -scheme foobarNightly SYMROOT=/Users/Me/buildAgent/work/e60c5dca158b2d23/Foobar/build OBJROOT=/Users/Me/buildAgent/work/e60c5dca158b2d23/Foobar/build test -sdk iphonesimulator8.1
```

it works. Any idea why this fails from the TeamCity build agent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, it looks like we've figured out the real problem. The `plist` file provided with TeamCity contains `SessionCreate` property, which should not be there for latest Mac OS X version.

The problem should be fixed in TeamCity 9.0.4, but as a workaround, you should place `jetbrains.teamcity.BuildAgent.plist` to 

`~/Library/LaunchAgents/jetbrains.teamcity.BuildAgent.plist`

and remove `SessionCreate` property and value from it.

The current variant of jetbrains.teamcity.BuildAgent.plist file is:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/agent/home/directory</string>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>jetbrains.teamcity.BuildAgent</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array> 
        <string>bash</string>
        <string>--login</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>launcher/bin/TeamCityAgentService-macosx-universal-32 -c ../conf/wrapper.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>logs/launchd.err.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>logs/launchd.out.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>`

Answer (score 5):

Per TeamCity's [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-UsingLaunchDaemonsStartupFilesonMacOS), there are two ways to create a build agent daemon on OS X:

- System-wide: `/Library/LaunchDaemons/jetbrains.teamcity.BuildAgent.plist`
- User-specific: `~/Library/LaunchAgents/jetbrains.teamcity.BuildAgent.plist`

It turns out that **neither** of these options will allow the TeamCity build agent to launch the Xcode Simulator.

If the build agent is manually started after directly (not SSH) logging into the build agent machine:

```
$ sh buildAgent/bin/agent.sh start
```

the TeamCity build agent will be able to launch the simulator. To run this script at startup, create a `.app` using Automator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445525/429533

Comment: Does anybody knows why so?