# Leaving "grunt watch" always running

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, command-line, twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, command

I'm using Bootstrap with LESS and it requires that I run the command `grunt watch` within the `/bootstrap` directory to watch for any changes to LESS files.

Is there a way to keep the command `grunt watch` always on so that I don't have to run it every time I re-open the terminal to my server?

Comment: Didn't you already edit your gruntfile for it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I think the closest you are doing to get is to set this task up as a default task http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#custom-tasks

Comment: Or possibly this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac

Comment: which server are you connecting to?