# How to run bash script on wake mac os x

Tags: bash, macos, wakeup

Want to change Wi-Fi settings on wake (osx).

I have script for that but don't want to run it manually every time.

Is there any way to run it on wake?

Comment: This might help, previous answer doesn't address wake: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27036/possible-to-run-scripts-on-sleep-and-wake

Answer (score 1):

This functionality of running script after waking up can be achieved with the powerful [hammerspoon](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon):

```lua
function printf(s,...)  print(s:format(...)) end
wather = hs.caffeinate.watcher.new(function(eventType)    
    -- screensDidWake, systemDidWake, screensDidUnlock
    if eventType == hs.caffeinate.watcher.systemDidWake then
        local output = hs.execute("/bin/echo -n hello", false)
        hs.notify.new({title="TestTitle", informativeText=output}):send()
        printf("%s, world", output)
    end
end)
wather:start()
```

Put those script to `$HOME/.hammerspoon/init.lua` and reload hammerspoon, and you can check the above /bin/echo output in the hammerspoon console.
There are several wake up events, including **screensDidWake**, **systemDidWake**, **screensDidUnlock**. See [wather api doc](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.caffeinate.watcher.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you out:

> [Running script upon login mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac) [closed]