# Mounted remote directory in MacOS is getting unmounted frequently

Tags: ios, macos, ubuntu-18.04, sshfs

I've installed `OSXFUSE` in my `Mac` and used `sshfs` to mount a remote directory which is hosted in a `Ubuntu` server (I usually `ssh` this server using `ssh username@ip`). This works fine, but I am frequently getting unmounted, which I again need to mount using `sshfs`.

Can somebody help me understand why it is happening and what is the way out? My host machine is running `MacOS Catalina` and remote machine is `Ubuntu 18`.

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As your ssh connection remains connected I guess your sshd configuration is Okay. Use -o reconnect option for sshfs. Like,

> sshfs USER@HOST:REMOTE_DIR MOUNT_DIR -o
>   auto_cache,**reconnect**,defer_permissions

Comment: Unfortunately this still fails to reconnect automatically when I restart my host (Mac)

Comment: If you want your mount persist on restart, then you should add this script on startup. This may help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac

Comment: I am still getting unmounted after few hours

Comment: Please check if it is the same for ssh connection, in that case you may need to tweak few ssh configuration in your server.