# Register c# .netcore console application to start at system boot on macOs

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, startup, macos-catalina

How can i programmatically in .net core, tell MacOS Catalina to startup my console application on system boot? I know that i can add program manually by Preferences:

> Open System Preferences.
> Go to Users & Groups.
> Choose your nickname on the left.
> Choose Login items tab.
> Press “+” and choose the app you’d like add.
> Then restart your Mac to see the changes.

But how to do this programmatically? Is this possible in .net core / zsh script?

Comment: Perhaps you can get c# code to run the program to execute this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372744/2057955

Comment: Thanks for idea, but my console application doesn't have info.plist file, and it's compiled as simple Unix executable.

Comment: plist is just XML aka just a text file. you can generate it in your c# code.

Comment: Okey i'll check that out :)

Comment: Note that if you place the .plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents or /Library/LaunchAgents, it'll run as an "agent" under a logged in user (*if and when* a user logs in, not strictly at boot). If you place it in /Library/LaunchDaemons, it'll run as a "daemon", as root independent of whoever may or may not be logged in. Choose appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add the `plist` for the application to the `LaunchAgents` folder for the user. The path on the mac is `/Library/LaunchAgents`.

If you wanted it to start up before the user logs in on the Mac you would add it to the `LaunchDaemons` folder found at: `/Library/LaunchDaemons`