# Running a python script everyday - Mac

Tags: python, bash, macos, automation

I want to run a python script everyday, the problem is, I can't schedule it for a specific time, because my laptop isn't guaranteed to be on at that time of day.

My idea was to put it in my .bash_rc file, and keep a txt file with dates in it, thus everytime I login and start a terminal, the python script would go and get the txt file and check to see if it has been run for that day yet, if it hasn't it will then execute the other commands.

I then read it's bad to put scripts in your .bash_rc (I think its .bash_profile on mac) especially lengthy ones. Is there somewhere else I could put this, or perhaps a way to put it in the .bash_rc so it doesn't hang up start up?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac

Does this help at all?

Comment: Look at launchd and anacron utilities.