# running a python script on Mac boot

Tags: python, macos, boot, launchd

I'm trying to get a python script to run on startup. I have the following file: com.test.service.plist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.test.service</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/var/www/html/app/appstart.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

copied to ~/Library/LaunchAgents/

loaded as

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.test.service.plist
```

the script has 2 lines:

```
/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/app/app.py
echo "hello" >> /var/www/html/app/test.txt
```

the script runs (the file test.txt gets created with 'hello' in it)
however, the app.py doesn't run. for testing purposes, all i did inside the app.py was:

```
import os
os.system("echo 'python' >> /var/www/html/app/test.txt")
```

if i just run the appstart.sh in terminal, then python runs no problem

i followed instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495949/get-python-script-to-run-on-boot-up-in-mac) already, but no luck

Comment: Why does your `app.py` script do the same thing as the bash script?

Comment: because I don't want to paste 200 lines of code in here and this is a very quick & easy way to test if the script runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I used cron to do just that. You can make an entry like this

`@reboot /path/to/my/script`

[more info about cron](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html)

The path to my script will be the path to your appstart.sh file.

So you open your terminal.

You type in `crontab -e` (this will open a file in your default editor, problably nano)

You scroll down and on the bottom of the file you type `@reboot /path/to/file`

Then you save and exit.

Comment: i know on apple site they advise against using cron, but it seems to be the only reliable task scheduler on OS X. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the .plist file is chmod 644.

You asked for "run on Mac boot" and "run on startup" which tells me you are in the wrong directory. LaunchAgents is for running scripts on user login.
To run on startup the .plist file needs to be in /Library/LaunchDaemons and owned by root:wheel.

If you don't need a shell to launch a shell script to launch python then I recommend a shortcut:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
    <string>/var/www/html/app/app.py</string>
</array>
```

Comment: in my case it doesn't matter actually, running on user login is fine too, but neither of those worked for me